# Why is tmap/shiny not removing previous layers?

Tags: r, shiny, tmap

I'm new to tmap and even newer to Shiny, so I hope that this question isn't a mistake on my part. I'm having problems with using tm_remove() with zindex, as the point data that should have been deselected still stays on the map. This is not an issue when using tmap_mode('view') or tmap_mode('plot') outside of RShiny.

The map is of river clarity values in New Zealand, with both size and colour representing these values. In the example below the Canterbury region (the south island, east coast, with the little peninsula) is being selected. All other bubbles should have disappeared:

[When selecting all regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfAZT.png)

[When selecting just Canterbury region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yox9J.png)

The code for testing this outside of RShiny can be seen below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)
library(jsonlite)
library(geojsonsf)
library(httr)
library(sf)
library(RColorBrewer)
library('shinydashboard')
library("DT")

# load river quality point data
# 1) water clarity
water_clarity <- st_read("water-clarity-19892013.shp")

# 2) ammonical nitrogen
am_nitrogen <- st_read("ammoniacal-nitrogen-trends-19892013.shp")

# 3) nitrate nitrogen
nitrate_nitrogen <- st_read("nitratenitrogen-trends-19892013.shp")

# merge all together into one data set (subset by npID)
full_rivers <- rbind(water_clarity, am_nitrogen)
full_rivers <- rbind(full_rivers, nitrate_nitrogen)

# get and subset region names of NZ
# get the unique names of all regions
region_names <- unique(nz_regions$REGC2020_V1_00_NAME) 

# convert to char and exclude 'outside region'
region_names <- as.character(region_names[1:16]) 

# lookup table of region names, for referencing in the server 
# when a region is selected
region_lookup <- c("Manawatū-Whanganui Region" = "HRC",
                   "Greater Wellington Region" = "GWRC",
                   "Nelson Region" = "NRC",
                   "Taranaki Region" = "TRC",
                   "Marlborough Region" = "MDC",
                   "Hawke's Bay Region" = "HBRC",
                   "Auckland Region" = "AC",
                   "Otago Region" = "ORC",
                   "Canterbury Region" = "ECAN",
                   "Tasman Region" = "TDC",
                   "Southland Region" = "ES",
                   "Gisborne Region" = "GDC",
                   "Bay of Plenty Region" = "BOP",
                   "west Coast Region" = "WCRC",
                   "Waikato Region" = "EW")


river_names <- full_rivers %>%
  select("river") %>%
  st_set_geometry(NULL)

# load regional TA shape
nz_regions <- st_read("regional-council-2020-generalised.gpkg")
nz_regions <- st_as_sf(nz_regions, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 2193)
  
    
### Subset rivers by indicator ###
ID <- "CLAR"
mapTitle <- "Water Clarity"
popups <- c("Water Clarity" = "T_Median", 
            "Dominant Landcover Type" = "LANDCOVER",
            "Location" = "location")
var_rivers <- full_rivers %>% filter(npID == ID)
    
# use lookup table to get region code for selected region
region_code <- unname(region_lookup['Canterbury Region'])

# filter the river data to the selected region
region_rivers <- var_rivers %>% dplyr::filter(srcid == region_code)

# change the bbox to encompass only that region
bbox <- nz_regions %>% filter(REGC2020_V1_00_NAME == 'Canterbury Region')

# This works as expected outside of shiny, only showing 
# the point data according to the selected region.
tmap_mode('view')
tm_shape(region_rivers, bbox = st_bbox(bbox)) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "T_Median",
           col = "T_Median",
           title.col = mapTitle,
           popup.vars = popups,
           palette = "-RdBu",
           style = "pretty",
           alpha = 0.5,
           id = "river",
           zindex = 401)
```

This is the relevant code used shiny application:

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cat("=== Loading primary map ===", "\n")
  
  process_rivers <- full_rivers
  ID <- "CLAR"
  mapTitle <- "Water Clarity"
  popups <- c("Water Clarity" = "T_Median", 
              "Dominant Landcover Type" = "LANDCOVER",
              "Location" = "location")
  first_map <- full_rivers %>% filter(npID == ID)
  bbox <- st_bbox(nz_regions)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(data = first_map, aes(x = T_Median)) +
        geom_density(fill = "blue") +
        labs(x = mapTitle)
    )}
  )
  
  output$map <- renderTmap({
    ### Begin the map output ###
    tm_shape(first_map) +
      tm_bubbles(size = "T_Median",
                 col = "T_Median",
                 title.col = mapTitle,
                 popup.vars = popups,
                 palette = "-RdBu",
                 style = "pretty",
                 alpha = 0.5,
                 id = "river",
                 zindex = 401) +
      tmap_options(basemaps = c(Canvas = "Esri.OceanBasemap"))
  })
  
  output$riverDT <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(first_map)
  })
  
### Loading new layer of selected data when loadbutton is clicked ###
observeEvent(input$loadbutton, { # shiny keeping an eye on the load button
    process_rivers <- full_rivers
    cat("=== Changing variables ===", "\n")
    
    ### Subset rivers by indicator ###
    if (input$indicator == "Water Clarity") {
      ID <- "CLAR"
      mapTitle <- "Water Clarity"
      popups <- c("Water Clarity" = "T_Median", 
                   "Dominant Landcover Type" = "LANDCOVER",
                   "Location" = "location")
      var_rivers <- process_rivers %>% filter(npID == ID)
    } else if (input$indicator == "Ammonium Nitrate") {
      ID <- "NH4N"
      mapTitle <- "Ammonium Nitrate"
      popups <- c("Ammonium Nitrate" = "T_Median", 
                   "Dominant Landcover Type" = "LANDCOVER",
                   "Location" = "location")
      var_rivers <- process_rivers %>% filter(npID == ID)
    } else if (input$indicator == "Nitrate Nitrogen") {
      ID <- "NO3N"
      mapTitle <- "Nitrate Nitrogen"
      popups <- c("Nitrate Nitrogen" = "T_Median", 
                   "Dominant Landcover Type" = "LANDCOVER",
                   "Location" = "location")
      var_rivers <- process_rivers %>% filter(npID == ID)
    } else {
      cat("=== This message shouldn't show ===", "\n")
    }
    
    ### Subset rivers by "srcid" variable ###
    cat("=== Changing selected rivers ===", "\n")
    
    if (input$region == "All regions") {
      
      ### Displaying all data (nothing needed to be done) ###
      cat("=== Displaying all rivers ===", "\n")
      region_rivers <- var_rivers
      bbox <- var_rivers
      
    } else {
      
      ### Taking the selected region and displaying only that data ###
      
      # use lookup table to get region code for selected region
      cat("=== A region was selected ===", "\n")
      region_code <- unname(region_lookup[input$region])
      cat("=== This is the selected region code: ", region_code, " === \n")
      
      # filter the river data to the selected region
      region_rivers <- var_rivers %>% dplyr::filter(srcid == region_code)
      
      # change the bbox to encompass only that region
      bbox <- nz_regions %>% filter(REGC2020_V1_00_NAME == input$region)
      
      # display in shell that change has taken place
      cat("=== This is the data after being filtered for the selected rivers: === \n")
      print(region_rivers$srcid)
    }
    
    ### Load a new map with the updated data ###
    cat("=== Loading new map ===", "\n")
    
    tmapProxy("map", session, {
      
      # Remove previous layer and add new layer
      cat("=== Layer Removed ===", "\n")
      tm_remove_layer(401) +
      tm_shape(region_rivers, bbox = st_bbox(bbox)) +
        tm_bubbles(size = "T_Median",
                   col = "T_Median",
                   title.col = mapTitle,
                   popup.vars = popups,
                   palette = "-RdBu",
                   style = "pretty",
                   alpha = 0.5,
                   id = "river",
                   zindex = 401) +
            tmap_options(basemaps = c(Canvas = "Esri.OceanBasemap"))
    })
```

Also, the version of tmap that is being used is 3.2.

Any help that could be offered would be greatly appreciated - I'm at a loss for why this is happening!